# How to extract specific line after regex match

Tags: regex

Given a keyword `Product data sheet` how can I extract 3rd line **only** after that match.

For example, given below data, output should be `XB4BW84M5`

```
Product data sheet
Characteristics
XB4BW84M5
```

I have tried `(Product data sheet)\r\n(.*?)(^.*\r\n){3}` but, that is to find something preceeded by 2 lines then the key word but, it extracts all 3 lines I need the 3rd only

Comment: What is your regex tool or language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this pattern: `(?<=Product data sheet)\r?\n.+\r?\n(.+)`

Explanation:

`(?<=Product data sheet)` - assert that what's preceding is `Product data sheet`

If assertion is true, then it matches new line character with `\r?\n`, then matches whole line with `.+`, which is "match one or more of any characters", then again, in order to match newline I used `\r?\n` and then used `(.+)` to store in capturing group second line after desired string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MJOeQX/2)

Comment: This still captures the 2nd line.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But you can use capturing group to get the desired result

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Then this would become impossible to achieve, as it would require positive lookbehind of variable length, which is only allowed in .NET. Moreover, what regex tools? I don't know any that doesn't support capturing group.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn FYI Beside .NET, unlimited length lookbehind is supported in JS ECMAScript 2018, PyPi regex Python module, Vim.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, good to know :) Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: A wrong match is likely if third line doesn't exist. You'd better replace `\s*` with `\r?\n` at least.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, running the regex in notepad++ captures 2nd and 3rd line but, I checked the demo and it seems there is a `full match` and `Group 1` how can I extract `Group 1` only

Comment: @fadytaher Using `\1` as substitution pattern